Could not resolve all files for configuration ':pdf_viewer_plugin:releaseCompileClasspath'

Trying to run flutter application after pub get step while running the Flutter project facing attached i.e related to pdf_viewer_plugin.
Facing attached issue with flutter project and pdf_viewer_plugin using for one of feature in flutter project.
Android Studio : Jellyfish
JAVA : 17
package name: pdf_viewer_plugin: ^2.0.1
flutter version: 3.19.6 (using fvm)
